# Java connection with sql server 2008 r2 type 4

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello iam using eclipse and sql server 2008 r2 as database i get a error like this

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host RITHISHABINAV, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.serv.sqlservertype4.fun(sqlservertype4.java:17)
at com.serv.sqlservertype4.main(sqlservertype4.java:39)
```

And my code is this

```
package com.serv;
```

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class sqlservertype4 {

```
void fun()
{
    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");                
        String connectionUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://RITHISHABINAV\\SQLEXPRESS;database=tempdatabase;integratedSecurity=true;";
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from customer");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("id"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));


        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    sqlservertype4 b= new sqlservertype4();
    b.fun();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a wrong `connectionURL`, you need to create a vURL` like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://HOST_SERVER:SQL_SERVER_PORT;databaseName=DATABASE_NAME;
```

But If you are using `Named Instances` to connect to your database (instead of PORT numbers), then use the following `URL` template

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DATABASE_HOST\\INSTANCE_NAME;databaseName=DATABASE_NAME;
```